# How to bring Tab layout inside a fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two fragments inside my activity. That works fine. Now inside one of my fragment, I need two tabbed contents. And in each tab, I need to inflate a view. How can I do that inside the oncreateview method? is it possible?

Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/texture_background"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="header"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25dp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my oncreateview method inside the fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_deals_fragment, container,false);
  TabHost tabs=(TabHost)view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  tabs.setup();
  TabHost.TabSpec tab = tabs.newTabSpec("my tab content");
  tab.setIndicator("my tab content");
  tabs.addTab(tab);
  return view;
}
```

Here is my error:

```
    11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.WrapperActivity}:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab content
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:225)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.example.fragments.SavedFragment.onCreateView(SavedDealsFragment.java:120)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5113)
11-19 21:29:32.666: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
```

do I need to provide any other details?

Comment: The exception tells you that you didn't set a content for your tabs. Use the method `setContent()` on *tab* with an implementation of `TabHost.TabContentFactory`.

Comment: yes. But what can I pass inside tab.setContent()? It expects a view id or intent. In my case I want to have a view inside each tab. How can I inflate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide the content for your tabs. You could use a `TabContentFactory` to build a content like this:

```
TabHost.TabSpec tab = tabs.newTabSpec("tab1");
tab.setIndicator("my tab content");
tab.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                if (tag.equals("tab1")) {
                    // create/inflate the view for the tab 1
                    return view;
                } else {
                    // the same as tab 1 for the other tabs if you have any             
            }
        });
tabs.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: I will try it out and let you know

Comment: says "TabContentFactory cannot be resolved to a type" and also there is no setTag method.

Comment: Wow. It works. Thanks @Luksprog. View is inflated. You saved my time. One more doubt. I am unable to get the tab headings with this. Because of that I am unable to move to next tab.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi I'm not sure I understand what is the last problem? How do you move to the next tab?

Comment: This just loads the content of first tab and not the header text that I am setting through setIndicator method.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi In your xml layout I see that you have set the visibility to `gone` for the `TabWidget`. Shouldn't that be made visible?